# How do you stop a loop from adding an extra iteration of a character in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, eof

So my code is as follows:

```
if (x > y)
{
    cout << "Sum of the values from " << y << " through " << x << " is: " << endl;
    while (x >= y)
    {
        cout << y << " + ";
        sum += y;
        y++;
    } 
    cout << " = " << sum << endl;

}
```

when this executes it has an extra addition sign at the end so it would output some thing like:

10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + = 46

I realize what the loop is doing, it makes sense to me why it would add that addition sign at the end, but I'm not sure where to put that statement. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to handle the end-case explicitly. I.e.,

```
cout << "Sum of the values from " << y << " through " << x << " is: " << endl;
while (x > y) //now the last case doesn't go through the loop
{
    cout << y << " + ";
    sum += y;
    y++;
}
cout << y << " = "; //instead it is handled here, and there will be no extra + sign
sum += y;
cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: thank you! for some reason I just assumed putting it outside the loop would cause it duplicate, but that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (x > y)
{
    cout << y << " + ";
    sum += y;
    y++;
} 

cout << y;
sum += y;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can write the following way

```
do
{
    cout << y;
    sum += y;
} while ( y++ < x && cout << " + " );
```

Or

```
while (x >= y)
{
    cout << y;
    if ( x != y ) cout << " + ";
    sum += y++;
}
```

Or

```
while (x >= y)
{
    cout << y << ( x == y ? " = " : " + " );
    sum += y++;
} 

cout << sum << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The probably easiest way is to punt:

Change

```
cout << " = " << sum << endl;
```

To

```
cout << " 0 = " << sum << endl;
```

That is the reason these are both allowed in C and C++:

```
int a[] = {1,2};
int b[] = {1,2,};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the plus sign before the number is much simpler :

```
if (x > y)
{
    int sum = y;
    cout << "Sum of the values from " << y << " through " << x << " is: " << endl << y;
    ++y;
    while (x >= y)
    {
        cout << " + " << y ;
        sum += y;
        y++;
    } 
    cout << " = " << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"\b" is a backspace escape sequence you can use this one to erase the final "+".

```
if (x > y)
{
    cout << "Sum of the values from " << y << " through " << x << " is: " << endl;
    while (x >= y)
    {
        cout << y << " + ";
        sum += y;
        y++;
    } 
    cout << "\b\b= " << sum << endl;     // Change is here...

}
```